# Windows Laptop not directly waking up from sleep and hibernation

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, hibernate

I have an Acer laptop (Extensa 4420) on which I installed Windows 7 a while ago.

It recently developed a problem where it often doesn't directly wake up from sleep or hibernation.

Instead, it takes 3 steps to successfully turn on:

- I wake it, and it goes into a blank screen state (the screen appears off, but the power indicator light is on).
- I put it back to sleep (using keyboard shortcut).
- I wake it again, this time successfully.

Any way I can get it to wake up in 1 step?

Comment: Do you have any unusual hardware, like an SSD or something? (I ask because I had to stop using Sleep when I installed my new SSD.)

Comment: No, regular hard drive. I suspected my SD card may have been causing issues, so I removed it. (Didn't do anything to its drivers though).

Comment: I once had some issues with the ATI graphics card, I don't know if there's any connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Anytime there are power-state issues, make sure you've got the latest drivers and the BIOS updated. Power state compatibility is tied very closely to drivers and the BIOS, and so keeping these updated is critical if you make use of Sleep and hibernate.

Is the issue the same whether you're using Sleep or Hibernate or are there any differences?

Comment: Its basically the same issue for both. It used to just be a problem for sleep, but now it also affects hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

I would try playing around with the power management settings to see if that will make a difference. Also, there's an FAQ about this subject that might be worth a read: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions